# Jungle blindness?

Tags: human-physiology, human-eye

Can people who live in green scenic areas like a jungle be more exposed to green light causing them to not be able to perceive green light as well as someone who may live in a desert void of color? Similar to snow blindness can strong color also blind a person to a spectrum of light but over a longer period of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Photokeratitis (snow blindness)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photokeratitis) is essentially a sunburn of the eye — it is caused by UV damage to the cornea.

Green wavelengths (no matter how vivid they might seem) don't have the same energy as UV wavelengths and are thus cannot cause the same kind of damage. (Which is not to say that you couldn't be blinded by a green laser, but that isn't a "natural" phenomenon.)

In addition, the amount of UV reflected from plants is typically very low:

> Generally, 85–95% of the UV-B radiation is absorbed by the leaf<sup>1</sup>.

This suggests that any sort of jungle blindness one might experience is highly unlikely to be related to what happens in photokeratitis — especially since any given photon will likely have been transmitted through and/or reflected by one or more leaves in any dense plant community.

I can't rule out some sort of psychological effect, but I have seen no evidence of that either in the literature or anecdotally.

**Reference**:

1: [Suchar, V. A., & Robberecht, R. (2015). Integration and scaling of UV‐B radiation effects on plants: from DNA to leaf. Ecology and evolution, 5(13), 2544-2555.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4523352/)